# Add CSS class to a div in code behind

Tags: c#, css

I have a div and I am trying to add a CSS class to it in code but I receive the following error when I try

```
Property or indexer 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlControl.Style' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only
```

I am using the following code:

```
protected void BTNEvent_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    BtnventCss.Style= "hom_but_a";                 
}
```

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

What if:

```
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CssClass="test1 test3 test-test" />
```

To add or remove a class, instead of overwriting all classes with

```
   BtnventCss.CssClass = "hom_but_a"
```

keep the HTML correct:

```
    string classname = "TestClass";

    // Add a class
    BtnventCss.CssClass = String.Join(" ", Button1
               .CssClass
               .Split(' ')
               .Except(new string[]{"",classname})
               .Concat(new string[]{classname})
               .ToArray()
       );

     // Remove a class
     BtnventCss.CssClass = String.Join(" ", Button1
               .CssClass
               .Split(' ')
               .Except(new string[]{"",classname})
               .ToArray()
       );
```

This assures

- The original classnames remain.
- There are no double classnames
- There are no disturbing extra spaces

Especially when client-side development is using several classnames on one element.

In your example, use

```
   string classname = "TestClass";

    // Add a class
    Button1.Attributes.Add("class", String.Join(" ", Button1
               .Attributes["class"]
               .Split(' ')
               .Except(new string[]{"",classname})
               .Concat(new string[]{classname})
               .ToArray()
       ));

     // Remove a class
     Button1.Attributes.Add("class", String.Join(" ", Button1
               .Attributes["class"]
               .Split(' ')
               .Except(new string[]{"",classname})
               .ToArray()
       ));
```

You should wrap this in a method/property ;)

Comment: Very helpful comprehensive answer!

Comment: Just to point that if the button have no class set to it by the time you call Button1.Attributes["class"], it returns null.

Answer (score 36):

`<div runat="server">` is mapped to a `HtmlGenericControl`.

Try using:

```
BtnventCss.Attributes.Add("class", "hom_but_a");
```

Answer (score 10):

For a non ASP.NET control, i.e. HTML controls like `div, table, td, tr`, etc. you need to first make them a server control, assign an ID, and then assign a property from server code:

#### ASPX page

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .top_rounded
        {
            height: 75px;
            width: 75px;
            border: 2px solid;
            border-radius: 5px;
            -moz-border-radius: 5px; /* Firefox 3.6 and earlier */
            border-color: #9c1c1f;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div runat="server" id="myDiv">This is my div</div>
    </form>
</body>
```

#### CS page

```
myDiv.Attributes.Add("class", "top_rounded");
```

Comment: This seems to replace all classes not just add one

Answer (score 8):

The [Style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlcontrol.style.aspx) property gets a collection of all the cascading style sheet (CSS) properties; you cannot set it.

Try `BtnventCss.CssClass = "hom_but_a";` instead.

I'm assuming BtnventCss is a WebControl.

I have just seen you're probably using `<div runat="server"...`

If so, you can try:

```
BtnventCss.Attributes.Add("class", "hom_but_a");
```

You could make the div an [asp:panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel.aspx) - they will render the same and you'll get better server-side support.

Comment: Wouldn't that generate style="class: hom_but_a" instead?

Answer (score 4):

Here are two extension methods you can use. They ensure any existing classes are preserved and do not duplicate classes being added.

```
public static void RemoveCssClass(this WebControl control, String css) {
  control.CssClass = String.Join(" ", control.CssClass.Split(' ').Where(x => x != css).ToArray());
}

public static void AddCssClass(this WebControl control, String css) {
  control.RemoveCssClass(css);
  css += " " + control.CssClass;
  control.CssClass = css;
}
```

Usage:     `hlCreateNew.AddCssClass("disabled");`

Usage:     `hlCreateNew.RemoveCssClass("disabled");`

Answer (score 2):

```
Button1.CssClass += " newClass";
```

This will not erase your original classes for that control. Try this, it should work.

Answer (score 1):

To **ADD** classes to html elements see [how to add css class to html generic control div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6517405/how-to-add-css-class-to-html-generic-control-div). There are answers similar to those given here but showing how to **add** classes to **html** elements.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also looking for the same solution. And I think of

`BtnventCss.CssClass = BtnventCss.CssClass + " hom_but_a";`

It seems working fine but I'm not sure if it is a good practice