# how to add css class to html generic control div?

Tags: c#, css

I created a div tag like this:

```
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl dynDiv = 
    new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("DIV");
```

I added style to the div tag like this:

```
dynDiv.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BorderStyle, "1px solid #DBE0E4");
dynDiv.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Height, "auto");
dynDiv.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.MarginTop, "5px");
dynDiv.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.PaddingBottom, "5px");
dynDiv.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Width, "682px");
```

But I need to control the style of the div tag through an external css file located at folder `~/css/maincss.css`.

How can I apply the css in that file to this div?

Comment: Add a class or ID to the div element, then you can do what you like with it in CSS.

Answer (score 95):

```
dynDiv.Attributes["class"] = "myCssClass";
```

Comment: This is true, though the other answers below accommodate for the class already being in the list of classes or not.

Answer (score 41):

To add a class to a div that is generated via the `HtmlGenericControl` way you can use:

```
div1.Attributes.Add("class", "classname");
```

If you are using the `Panel` option, it would be:

```
panel1.CssClass = "classname";
```

Comment: technically that replaces the class. It doesn't add it. You can use dynDiv.Attributes["class"] += "myCssClass";

Comment: @GarrGodfrey Remember to add a space between classes.

Answer (score 13):

if you want to add a class to an existing list of classes for an element:

```
element.Attributes.Add("class", element.Attributes["class"] + " " + sType);
```

Answer (score 6):

My approach would be:

```
/// <summary>
/// Appends CSS Class seprated by a space character
/// </summary>
/// <param name="control">Target control</param>
/// <param name="cssClass">CSS class name to append</param>
public static void AppendCss(HtmlGenericControl control, string cssClass)
{
    // Ensure CSS class is definied
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cssClass)) return;

    // Append CSS class
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(control.Attributes["class"]))
    {
        // Set our CSS Class as only one
        control.Attributes["class"] = cssClass;
    }
    else
    {
        // Append new CSS class with space as seprator
        control.Attributes["class"] += (" " + cssClass);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think the answer of Curt is correct, however, what if you want to add a class to a div that already has a class declared in the ASP.NET code.

Here is my solution for that, it is a generic method so you can call it directly as this:

Asp Net Div declaration:

```
<div id="divButtonWrapper" runat="server" class="text-center smallbutton fixPad">
```

Code to add class:

```
divButtonWrapper.AddClassToHtmlControl("nameOfYourCssClass")
```

Generic class:

```
public static class HtmlGenericControlExtensions
{
    public static void AddClassToHtmlControl(this HtmlGenericControl htmlGenericControl, string className)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(className))
            return;

        htmlGenericControl
            .Attributes.Add("class", string.Join(" ", htmlGenericControl
            .Attributes["class"]
            .Split(' ')
            .Except(new[] { "", className })
            .Concat(new[] { className })
            .ToArray()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Where should I put that Generic class?

Comment: You can put it a Util folder of your web application.

Comment: That's a folder that I create for that purpose?

Comment: Yes, but in theory you can put it wherever you want. It's only for organization purposes.

Answer (score 3):

If you're going to be repeating this, might as well have an extension method:

```
// appends a string class to the html controls class attribute
public static void AddClass(this HtmlControl control, string newClass)
{
    if (control.Attributes["class"].IsNotNullAndNotEmpty())
    {
        control.Attributes["class"] += " " + newClass;
    }
    else
    {
        control.Attributes["class"] = newClass;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't add the css file to the div, you add a class to it then put your import at the top of the HTML page like so:

```
<link href="../files/external.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Then add a class like the following to your code: 'myStyle'.

Then in the css file do something like:

```
.myStyle
{
   border-style: 1px solid #DBE0E4;
}
```

Comment: And how do you get the `.myStyle` class onto the html element? That's what the OP's question is asking.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative approach if you want to add a class to an existing list of classes of an element:

```cs
element.Attributes["class"] += " myCssClass";
```

Answer (score 1):

How about an extension method?

Here I have a show or hide method. Using my CSS class *hidden*.

```
public static class HtmlControlExtensions
{
    public static void Hide(this HtmlControl ctrl)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ctrl.Attributes["class"]))
        {
            if (!ctrl.Attributes["class"].Contains("hidden"))
                ctrl.Attributes.Add("class", ctrl.Attributes["class"] + " hidden");
        }
        else
        {
            ctrl.Attributes.Add("class", "hidden");
        }
    }

    public static void Show(this HtmlControl ctrl)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ctrl.Attributes["class"]))
            if (ctrl.Attributes["class"].Contains("hidden"))
                ctrl.Attributes.Add("class", ctrl.Attributes["class"].Replace("hidden", ""));
    }
}
```

Then when you want to show or hide your control:

```
myUserControl.Hide();

//... some other code

myUserControl.Show();
```