# Change CSS in backend

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, css

When using asp.net, is it possible to modify css properties in the c# back end code in the same as Div tags? I cannot get it to work.

For example:

**HTML**

```
<div id="myDiv" runat="server" style="height:10px; color:black;" />
```

**C#**

```
myDiv.Style.Add("color", "white");
```

This works, however I am trying to do the same to a css class instead. So if I had:
**CSS**

```
 .myDivStyle
    {
       height:10px;
       color:black;
    }
```

How can I access this and change the color in c#? The only effective way I was able to find was to have two css classes and replace the class with another one such as the answer to this: [Replacing css class solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175381/how-to-edit-css-style-of-a-div-using-c-sharp-in-net)

I have tried:

```
myDivStyle.Style.Add("color","white");
```

I was wondering if it is possible to include the runat="server" property directly to the css class. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
myDiv.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("color", "white");
```

This is how I do by adding CSS for the same based on the condition.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for. A way to modify a css class, not replace it.

Comment: I am glad I was of some help.

Answer (score 2):

Apply the CSS class via attributes, like this:

```
myDiv.Attributes["class"] = "myDivStyle";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Attributes like `myDiv.Attributes.Add("class", "myDivStyle");`
This is will add new class to div

Answer (score 0):

For add a CSS class through code behind (In C#) :

```
myDiv.Attributes.Add("class", "top_rounded");
```

OR

**C#**

```
divControl.Attributes["class"] = "myClass";
```

**VB**

```
divControl.Attributes("class") = "myClass"
```

You'll need to have a rule like this one on your css file

```
.myClass
{
   height:200px; 
   /*...more styles*/
}
```

[Check This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742010/add-css-class-to-a-div-in-code-behind)